# What is meant by freezer?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, storage

I came across the word related to **freezer** in several statements as follows

Regarding chicken

> Raw chicken pieces can be stored in the **freezer** for up to 9 months,
> while a whole chicken can be frozen for up to one year. Cooked chicken
> can be stored in the **freezer** for 2–6 months. [Source](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/how-long-does-chicken-last-in-the-fridge#refrigeration)

and regarding mushrooms

> To further extend the shelf life of cooked mushrooms, **freeze** them;
> **freeze** in covered airtight containers or heavy-duty **freezer** bags.
> [Source](https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17751)

I know about deep-fridge of an refrigerator, which is used to store small ice-cubes. Is it the freezer? Or any other container?

Answer (score 11):

The terms *freezer* and *deep freeze* are synonymous. There is no such term as  "deep fridge" in British or US English, though apparently there is in Indian English… where if you search what you find are chest freezers.

This means, whatever your terminology, a 'freezer', 'deep freeze' or 'deep fridge' is **not** the same as an ordinary ice box inside a refrigerator.

Small domestic refrigerators have an 'ice box', really little more than an enclosed but not sealed area where the actual cooling elements of the fridge operate. This is sufficient to make ice cubes, but not cold enough for long term freezer storage.

In the EU, ice boxes & dedicated freezers have a 'star' system which tells you how capable the box is for long term storage, from one to four stars.
If there are fewer than three stars, then you should consider it for short term storage only.
Ice boxes can have up to three stars, only a true dedicated freezer can have four.
If there are no stars, then don't use it for anything other than making ice cubes.

Apparently the US has no official designation or rating for consumer guidance. I cannot guess how you may be able to tell whether your ice box is safe with no ratings system at all; other than if it has a thermometer in each section.

> **[What do the star ratings mean on my Fridge/Freezer?](https://www.smeg-service.co.uk/support/knowledgebase/article/2711/what-do-the-star-ratings-mean-on-my-fridge-freezer)**
> * One star (-6 degrees centigrade) is perfect for making ice cubes and is sufficiently cold to keep food for three or four days.
> ** Two stars (-12 degrees centigrade) stores food for fifteen to twenty days.
> *** Three stars (-18 degrees centigrade) will keep food safe for up to three months.
> **** Four stars (below 18 degrees centigrade) means that the compartment provides the ideal conditions for freezing down fresh and pre-cooked foods

Dedicated freezers, or larger refrigerators with a dedicated, separate freezer section [accessible by a separate sealed door, & not enclosed within the fridge itself] should all be three or four stars.

Refs -
[EU Regulation 1060/2010 fridge freezer labels..](http://www.euenergylabels.com/EU-Regulation-1060-2010-fridge-freezer-labels.htm)
Wikipedia - [Refrigerator; Temperature zones and ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerator#Temperature_zones_and_ratings)

Comment: +1 though I'm not happy with your quote - Smeg seem to be combining safety and quality, and then imply disagreement with themselves in the last quote sentence given that fridge ice-boxes are commonly 1* (or they imply you should eat all your ice cream in 3-4 days - challenge accepted).  Maybe their current fridges have better than 1* ice boxes. BTW one star is often *better* for ice cream that's to be served reasonably soon

Comment: Ice cream is spoon-bendingly rock-like at -18°, at -6° it's much nicer. tbh, I don't have an ice box other than in what I consider my 'beer fridge'  in which it's merely 'an area I can't use cos there's a box in the way' my 'proper' fridge has 3 sections, at 4°, 0.5° & -18°. I often lift ice cream up into the 0.5 section for an hour or two before serving.

Comment: This answer seems to be highly location specific. As far as I know this star system doesn't exist in the US, and probably not where OP is, either. The assertion that they're is no such tem as "deep fridge" is also highly suspect.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Star ratings are EU. The US apparently has no safety regulation at all for consumer guidance. I'm afraid I can't include information that doesn't exist.  'Deep fridge' turns out to be an Indian English misnomer for 'deep freeze' or 'chest freezer'. Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

This is a note on the terminology - for the use see Tetsujin's answer.

A freezer is a food-storage device that goes below freezing (0°C).  This may be

- a standalone unit

  - with a door opening forwards
  - with a lid opening upwards, also called a "chest freezer" or "deep freeze"*
- the colder compartment in a fridge-freezer (often the lower one as shown in this picture)

[image: fridge-freezer]

- A compartment inside a fridge - first you open the fridge then you open the freezer compartment. This is sometimes called an "ice-making compartment", for the lowest specifications or "ice box", though that can also be used to refer to other things (small low-spec standalone freezers, no longer common, or even unpowered insulated boxes designed to be filled with ice)

* "Deep freeze" is also used more generally to refer to freezers excluding ice making compartments.  Many foods will store indefinitely in these (from a safety point of view; quality may suffer)

<sub>Image by [Wikipedia user Sannse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Sannse)  CC-BY-SA-3.0</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most refrigerators include a freezer compartment (either as an insulated area inside the main refrigerator compartment, or as a separately reached, generally smaller compartment), where ice is made; the term "deep fridge" and "freezer" are synonyms. There are also separate freezers available, though those are less common in households.

Comment: Sorry, but this is ambiguous at best.

Comment: I disagree with the last statement - depending on where you live and how you organize your household, a separate freezer is a given.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, the freezer compartment in small fridges is rarely suitable for long term storage.

Comment: @Stephie Can you think of a household that has a freezer but not a refrigerator? Can you think of a household that has a refrigerator but not a freezer? If your answers are "no" and "yes", then clearly freezers are less common.

Comment: The main issue is not the ubiquity or otherwise of separate freezers. That's merely a distraction.

Comment: @GdD By "compartment" I'm not (just) referring to the icemaker in very small refrigerators. In "normal" refrigerators, this compartment has a separate door, rather than being inside the refrigerated compartment. It is commonly used for long-term storage.

Comment: @Sneftel, that is not what comes out in your answer.

Comment: @GdD Fair enough, edited.

Comment: Works for me @Sneftel.

Comment: There's still no such thing as a 'deep fridge'; & your separation of the terms ice box & freezer is not clear.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's what I originally thought too, but it does seem to be used in Indian English. I didn't want to get into the "freezer" versus "ice compartment" thing, since (as you described in your answer) freezers are very much along a continuum (and if all you have is a teeny ice compartment, well, that's gonna have to suffice).

Comment: @Sneftel I stand by my comment. I know of enough families that opted for a refrigerator sans freezer compartment (to maximize refrigerator space, especially for built-in units) and a separate freezer. And some will supplement their fridge-freezer setup with an additional freezer. We can of course agree to disagree.

Comment: but it won't suffice… that's the entire issue. If someone mistakes an ice box for a freezer & uses it to keep chicken for 6 months...

Comment: I now have exactly the setup @Stephie describes; in the past I've had to supplement a fridge-with-ice-box with a whole extra fridge because of the lost space - but needed a proper freezer too